# Cannot assign "'18'": "Pedido_Extra.especialidad_ex" must be a "Especialidad" instance

Tags: python, django

I have this error when saving the entered data of the form of the model, and I also want to save the id of the specialty captured in get, how to solve it? Any help please!

views.py:

```
def PedidoExtra(request, id_especialidad):
especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
if request.method == 'GET':
  form = ExtraForm()
else:
  form = ExtraForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    esp = form.save(commit=False)
    esp.especialidad_ex = id_especialidad
    esp.save()
    form.save()

return render(request, 'form2.html', {'form':form, 'especialidad':especialidad})
```

Comment: Pedido_Extra has no especialidad_ex.  
Now I see this error, a regret that the field exists and is called especialidad_ex_id of Pedido_Extra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you what's wrong; it's expecting an instance of Especialidad, but you're passing the ID.

You already get the instance in your code; you should just use it.

```
esp.especialidad_ex = especialidad
```